# Present Perfect- How to determine time interval?

Tags: present-perfect

I have two questions

1. If I'm talking about life experience how can I determine the time interval? For example: "I've seen this movie many times before, I don't want to see it again" or "I've eaten sushi before, it's really tasty" so what's the time interval for these examples?
2. I just want to know if I understood this well or not. When I say "I've taken a lot of beautiful photos since I bought this camera" so this is an unfinished action, and its interval starts when I bought the camera until now, and it will continue to the future. Is it correct?

Comment: Actually, "_I've taken a lot of beautiful photos_" describes a _completed_ action, not an unfinished one. _"I've taken"_ = _"I have taken"_, which is the _past perfect_; _perfect_ means _completed_ or _finished._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think the term *past perfect* is more properly reserved for forms such as "I *had taken*", whereas "I *have taken*" is the *present perfect*.

Answer (score 2):

No timespan is specified in your first two examples; we can only infer that you saw the movie and ate sushi at some time between your birth and the moment of speaking.

The timespan in your third example runs from the time you bought the camera to the moment of speaking. The sentence does not imply that you will continue to take pictures with it—it is silent on that subject—but of course the state, your experience of having taken those pictures in the past, will continue indefinitely.

Comment: The first two examples the time interval is my life isn't it ? So it should continue to the future or it ends now "the moment of speaking" ?

Comment: @Mmm It includes only the past up to the present.